# angularUI duplicates my function

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

Hi guys, I have a strange problem with my angular app. I'm trying to use the bootstrap-ui modal, but every time that I use it, my app creates a duplicate. I can't fiddle the project because it's too big, but I will try to explain it better with an example.

Code for the modal:

```
<div ng-controller="modalCtrl">
<script type="text/ng-template" id="login.html">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h3>Benvenuto</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <form ng-submit="login()">
            <input id="focusedInput" class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="data.username" placeholder="username" popover="inserisci qui il tuo username" popover-trigger="focus" popover-placement="right"><br>
            <input id="focusedInput" class="form-control" type="password" ng-model="data.password" placeholder="password"popover="inserisci qua la tua password" popover-trigger="focus" popover-placement="right"><br>
            <input class="btn-primary btn-lg" type="submit" value="Login">
        </form>
    </div> 
</script>
```

this is my modal view:

```
BIappCtrl.controller('modalCtrl',function ($scope, $modal) {
    var open = function () {
        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
                templateUrl: 'login.html',
                controller: this.loginCtrl
        });
    };
    open();
});
```

And that's the controller. It goes technically ok, my app creates the modal, but it does it two times, creating the modal one over the other, so I'll close one and every time I find another one under it. This strange thing happends one time yet, when I try to use the ui-route rather then ngRoute module, do you have any ideas?

Comment: You might want to move your solution to an answer and mark the question as answered.

Comment: You should add your solution as an answer and then select it as the correct one rather than edit the question and put the answer there.

Comment: As others have said, do not put your answer into the question. It should be its own answer.

Comment: yes you are right, but i'm new and i can't answer to my own question before eight hour since i've submit that, so for now i have add my answer to the question, as soon as i can i will move my that one to the right place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i've solved the problem and i will write the solution, even if it is simple.
The mistake was mine,i've wrongly understand the ngRoute module, so in my app.js file i've insert the controllers for every view, even if that controllers was written in the div too.
Here the mistake:

```
BIapp.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/menu', {
            templateUrl: 'views/menu.html',
            //controller: 'menuCtrl'
      }).when('/modal', {
            templateUrl: 'views/modal.html',
            //controller: 'modalCtrl'
      })
        .when('/search',{
            templateUrl: 'views/search.html',
            //controller: 'searchCtrl'
        })
        .when('/varie',{
            templateUrl: 'views/varie.html',
            //controller: 'varieCtrl'
        })
        .when('/logout',{
            templateUrl: 'views/logout.html',
            //controller: 'logoutCtrl'
        }).
        otherwise({
            redirectTo:'/menu'
        });

 }]);
```